# Date display format using phpMyAdmin SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

when I run my SQL in phpMyAdmin my datetime field (pm_expense_ledger.hos_date) is displaying in this format: 2019-10-01 00:00:00

Although this isn't the end user GUI, how can I format the datetime field to just display as DDMMMYYYY ("%d %b %Y") as I don't need the tine when I run my query?

You can see I've tried as few times unsuccessfully!

Code:

```
    SELECT pm_expense_ledger_el_connector.property_id AS PropId,
    /*    show FIELDS from pm_expense_ledger; to view field column types */
        pm_expense_ledger.hos_date AS Date, /* this is a datetime field */
    /*    DATE_FORMAT('pm_expense_ledger.hos_date', '%d%b%Y') AS FDate,    returns null values */
    /*    DATE_FORMAT("pm_expense_ledger.hos_date", "%d %b %Y %H-%i-%S") AS D1,*/
    /*    DATE('pm_expense_ledger.hos_date', '%d %b %Y') AS D2,*/
    /*    DATE("pm_expense_ledger.hos_date", "%d %b %Y") AS D3, no difference using single or double quotes */
    /*    DATA_TYPE('pm_expense_ledger.hos_date'),*/
        pm_homeowner_statement_key.key_name AS Item,
        pm_expense_ledger_description.descr AS Description,
        pm_expense_ledger_el_connector.hos_total AS HOS,
        pm_expense_ledger.pm_expense_ledger_id AS pmelid,
        pm_expense_ledger.expense_ledger_id AS elid
    FROM  pm_expense_ledger_el_connector
    JOIN pm_expense_ledger
        on pm_expense_ledger.pm_expense_ledger_id = pm_expense_ledger_el_connector.pm_exp_ledger_id
    JOIN pm_expense_ledger_description
        on pm_expense_ledger_description.pm_el_description_id = pm_expense_ledger.pm_exp_ledg_descr_id
    JOIN pm_homeowner_statement_key
        on pm_homeowner_statement_key.pm_hos_key_id = pm_expense_ledger.pm_hos_key_id

    where pm_expense_ledger.hos_date BETWEEN '2019,12,01' and '2019,12,31'
    /*group by pm_expense_ledger_el_connector.property_id*/
    order by pm_expense_ledger_el_connector.property_id ASC, pm_expense_ledger.hos_date ASC, pm_expense_ledger_id ASC;
```

Comment: It's typically more efficient to let the database return the raw binary datetime value and have the client application worry about the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
DATE_FORMAT(pm_expense_ledger.hos_date, '%d%b%Y') AS FDate
```

The following attempt was close:

> DATE_FORMAT('pm_expense_ledger.hos_date', '%d%b%Y')

It fails because of the single quotes surrounding the column name, which make it a string; since this string cannot be converted to a `datetime`, `date_format()` yields a `null` value.

Bottom line: in MySQL, don't use quotes (single or double) around identifiers; if for some reason you need to quote an identifier (because it contains special characters), then you need to use backticks (`).